What to do when training and validation loss both keep decreasing and seem correlated?
I'm training a neural network (a custom architecture, but mostly a variant of a CNN) with an MSE loss.  The trained network works well for my task (predicting one vector from another vector) - like, test loss is low enough where the network has clearly learned something and is useful.  However, the training results from my network do not look normal.  As shown in the plot below, (1) training and validation loss both seem to always decrease, even after 1,000 epochs; (2) the validation loss curve never starts to go up and form the U shape I'd expect to see (some inflection point where you start to overfit); and (3) the validation loss and training loss seem to follow each other extremely closely, even though my training and validation sets are disjoint.

My questions are: (1) is there ever a scenario where this might be considered "okay?"  Assuming the answer is no, (2) how should I go about debugging why these loss curves are behaving this way, and ultimately, to get training results that look more standard?
